# Execute a method after the completion of another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

In my app i have two methods, storeData and gotoNextView. I want the gotoNextPage to be executed after storeData method has completed execution. In storeData i am saving the token obtained after sucessful login using Egocache, in gotoNextPage i have code which is used to load a new view controller, in the next viewcontroller i have to use the token for fetching the other details. But the problem the method gotoNextView is being executed before the storeData so i am gettin null token in the next view.

I have tried using the following :

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {

    [self storeData];

});



dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {


    [self gotoNextPage];
```

the above code is serving the purpose but when i am using the above code, the NSUrlConnections in the next view are not loading.

```
[self storeData];

[self performSelector:@selector(gotoNextPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

this code is working and the NSUrlConnections in next view also working, but is there a better way to achieve this purpose

Comment: show `storeData` method code

Comment: Your code should work and execute the second block after the first one has finished. So what is the problem with the NSURLConnections ? - And why don't you just call both methods in the first block?

Comment: @MartinR that's what i also dint understand.. why the nsurl block are not working

Comment: @BalaChandra: The problem might be that you don't call the NSURLConnection on the main thread ...

Answer (score 4):

You could pass a completion block to the storeData method. That way storeData can let you know when it's finished doing what it needs to do, instead of you trying to guess.

```
- (void)storeDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    // Store Data Processing...
    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
}

// Calling storeDataWithCompletion...
[self storeDataWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self gotoNextPage];
    });
 }];
```

The dispatch_async to the main queue is not required. I added that since gotoNextPage is UI related and it's not clear what thread storeDataWithCompletion: would call the completion block from.

[Here's a link to Apple's documentation on blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Hope this helps.